# How come so many Java textbooks have Swing examples that don't use runnable?

Tags: java, swing, runnable

I'm new here, and to Java.  I suspect this question is too open ended for this area, but for the life of me I can't find a more suitable place.  I also haven't turned up anything when searching the internet.

I have a number of Java textbooks, mostly somewhat older editions that are less expensive to purchase.  For many of them, the Swing examples do not use the runnable interface and the event dispatching queue.   (for example, "How to Program Java, 7th edition", by Deitel and Deitel, 2007, or "Java for Dummies, 5th edition", Barry Burd, 2011, or "Sams Teach Yourself Java in 24 Hours, 6th edition", Rogers Cadenhead, 2012).

Can anyone tell me why that is?
Is it for simplicity?
Since when has it been the recommended practice to use the event dispatching queue (runnable has been available since JDK 1.0)?
Or something else?

Comment: 1) Programming idiom changes over time; 2) What did they do instead in the olden days of HtPJ 7th Ed?

Comment: I can only speculate.  Simple Swing GUI's work whether or not the GUI is started on the Event Dispatch thread with an EventQueue or SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  It's when you get into using additional threads, like with animation, that the lack of an invokeLater causes hard to diagnose problems.  I've been using invokeLater since Java 4, so it's been recommended practice since then.

Comment: HtPJ 7th edition was written way back in 2007.  In all fairness, it does mention the event dispatch queue, but not until page 1059, well after swing is introduced.  For the earlier swing chapters, one class will extend JFrame, then a test class will create and setVisible an instance of the extended JFrame class.

Comment: That's a different issue.  A Java class should only be extended when you want to override one or more of the methods in the class.  I understand the need not to introduce too many Java concepts at one time, but most people never get instruction beyond the simple extend JFrame.

Comment: I was replying to Andy Turner's question.  I suspect I am not writing clearly due to my lack of experience.  For the Swing examples in HtPJ 7th, Runnable/the event dispatch queue isn't used, the GUI object is simply instantiated in a regular main method. However, for even the simple examples in the Oracle Java Tutorial, Runnable is used.  For some reason this is irking me when I try and work through the examples in the book.

Answer (score 1):

Well Sun changed the recommendations over time. Earlier everybody thought it was ok to instanciate Swing Components off the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)

See [Will the real Swing Single Threading Rule please stand up?](https://bitguru.wordpress.com/2007/03/21/will-the-real-swing-single-threading-rule-please-stand-up/)

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting.